# Check for specific program files in NSIS

Tags: windows, file, installation, nsis

I am working on a program which needs to only be installable on the company's PCs to prevent it being run on other computers. The only thing all the computers have in common/distinguishes them is an .exe file in the same place on every PC (i.e. C:\Program Files\program_name\program.exe).

The .exe is not always running so I cannot use nsProcesss.

Is there a way to check for this file before installing and abort if it is not present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution to my problem:

```
IfFileExists "C:\Program Files\program_name\program.exe" file_found file_not_found
file_not_found:
StrCpy $0 "This computer is not valid"
Abort

file_found:

;rest of .nsi
```

`IfFileExists` checks if the following file exists. Goes to either `file_found` or `file_not_found`. I choose to abort if file is not_found

Comment: “Program Files” differs according to the OS language, `$PROGRAMFILES` should be safer (unless the program is available in a 64-bit version as well). Also keep in mind that the user can install the program in any other folder he pleases.

Comment: Hi @idleberg, it most cases you are correct that $PROGRAMFILES is a better way. However in this case the line is being used to ensure that it is the correct operating system it is being installed on (an embedded version windows XP) so in this case the "Program Files" is actually the preferred solution